# .htaccess rewrite to the same url and pass get params

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

All the examples I see with RewriteRule are something like `RewriteRule ^([a-z])$ index.php?example=$1`

But I have the following case: I want the

> example.com/en/something

to rewrite to

> example.com/something?lang=en

And that applies to all things in the place of **something**.
Basically I want to only take the first parameter if it's **en** or **ru** and rewrite to the same link but only to pass it as a get parameter

So

> example.com/en/something-else/anything

also rewrites to

> example.com/something-esle/anything?lang=en

How can I do that ?

**UPDATE**
I tried this `RewriteRule ^(en|ru)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1` but it says that the page is not found (it returns the 404 page from my application not from the server).

Comment: Please define what you mean by "rewrite" here? ***Redirect?*** Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476.

Comment: No, I want when I enter example.com/en/something to be able in the code to do something like `$data['lang'] = $_GET['lang']`, so the server must accept that as example.com/something?lang=en. Also there's the issue: how do I get only the first parameter if it matches *en* or *ru*

Comment: Does your url `example.com/something-esle/anything?lang=en` work if you type it in browser address bar?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it after all.
This is my .htaccess now:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /avc0135/

#Language
RewriteRule ^(en|ru|bg)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(en|ru|bg)$ ?lang=$1
#Language

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After a few searches on how exactly does .htaccess works I managed to figure out the RewriteRule, the problem after that was that the `#Language` block was at the bottom, I moved before everything else and it worked.